# Apparent altering of Tex Live Utility's "umask"

Tags: texlive, mactex

Yesterday, I installed the TeX Live Utility update to version 1.15. After downloading and installing and relaunching TeX Live Utility, I got the following message:

> **You have altered the system's umask**
>
> The normal umask is 022 and yours is set to 022. This more restrictive
> umask may cause permission problems with TeX Live.

I have three questions:

1. What exactly is a `umask`?
2. Should I be concerned about this message? (I've never done anything, as far as I'm aware, to alter the `umask`, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this message to begin with.)
3. And, finally, as far as I can tell "022" is the exact same as "022", so does anyone have any idea *why* I might be getting this message?

Comment: You should post this on the `mactex` mailing list instead. Umask is a feature on Unix systems (like Linux and Mac) telling the system which permissions a newly created file should have by default. Someone clearly made a mistake in that update.

Comment: @daleif It's already reported on the texlive mailing list.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is there any value in leaving this question on TeX.SX, then, or should I just delete it?

Comment: (@daleif, too).

Comment: @Adam there has been no reply yet (but I assume it's a bug) but it is probably worth leaving this question here for a bit, just so people know it is not "just them". Once the bug is fixed this should be closed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sounds like a good plan.

Comment: This has been posted to texlive list by a (presumably different) Adam 
`I've just released another update to fix this problem; the
test was incorrect. Sorry for the trouble.`   So if you wait for a mirror to catch up and do an update, the problem should go.

Comment: Bug umask check fixed with version 1.16 of Tex Live Utility now available.